# How and why to conjugate verb with and/or subject

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, conjugation

Which of the following statements is correctly conjugated? Is there a rule or explanation for conjugating verbs with ***and/or*** subjects?

> The X and/or Y **is** true.

or

> The X and/or Y **are** true.

Does the plurality of `X` and `Y` matter?

Comment: It depends. Are x and y singular? Or, is x (and y) plural?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Good question, I'll add it to the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a singular or plural verb after "and/or"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134703/using-a-singular-or-plural-verb-after-and-or)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm also asking for the reason, but apologies.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I often close a question when there is a duplicate question which contains one or preferably more answers, but I fail to see how this post: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/134719/44619, despite it being accurate and clear, actually *answers* any of the two questions at hand. It totally avoids the issue of two singular or plural subjects joined with **and/or** imo. I am ignoring the comment(s) below the duplicate (besides there's only one) because it wasn't posted as an answer.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I accept that the earlier question doesn't have any particularly good (and/or comprehensive :) *answers*. But if there *were* a decent answer there, I don't see how it could fail to address both questions here. Personally, although I didn't downvote it myself, don't I think much of the only answer here currently, because it (mistakenly, imho) implies that there are absolute "rules" which can *always* be applied to distinguish "correct" and "incorrect" usages...

Comment: So far as I'm concerned, neither [*husband and/or wife **are***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22husband+and+or+wife+are%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) nor [*husband and/or wife **is***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22husband+and+or+wife+is%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are particularly "correct" anyway - but that's simply because ***and/or*** is an "iffy" construction which doesn't really admit of "rules" in the first place.

Comment: (but I have no strong opinion on whether I could and/or should have said *"**is** particularly correct"* in that last comment, so what do I know? :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers you may not have downvoted but you suggested the duplicate question, and as far as questions go, this one is clearer and should be left open. Perhaps offering a bounty will make it receive more attention.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I've posted a bounty on the *earlier* question. Perhaps [*neither you nor I **am** right*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22among+them+these+Neither+you%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but that seems like slavish adherence to an ugly/misconceived "rule". In practice, writers seem to very much prefer [*neither you nor I **are***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22neither+you+nor+I+are%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). If rule-based grammarians can get even *neither/no* so wrong, they're likely to make even more of a mess of *and/or*. But let's see what comes of it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, let's! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually, it doesn't matter one darn bit if the subjects joined by "and" are singular or plural.

---

**- Rule 1: Subjects joined by "and" will *always* be plural.**

is = singular verb ||||  are = plural verb

*Tom and I* **are** awesome. (**plural**)

*Those girls and I* **are** awesome. (**plural**)

*Those girls and boys* **are** awesome. (**plural**)

---

**- Rule 2: For subjects joined by "or" or "nor", you look at the subject closest to the verb.**

is = singular verb |||| are = plural verb

Either *those girls **or Tom*** **is** awesome.  ('Tom' is closest to the verb, so we use a **singular** verb.)

Either *Tom **or those girls*** **are** awesome. ('Girls' is closest to the verb, so we use a **plural** verb.)

---

**Edit**: To accommodate JanusBahsJacquet's interpretation of this question, I will also answer his question.

When using and/or or or/and, you use the latest conjunction in time.

In the case of "and/or", we would use "or":

Angie and/or Tom is going to pay for this. (We use the singular "is" and not the plural "are" because we are applying the "or" rule.)

Comment: Neither of these rules is quite correct.  First, sentences like "Drinking and driving is a serious problem" are quite common.  Second, different speakers resolve number conflicts in disjunctive subjects different ways; see http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=1293 for some discussion.

Comment: @snailboat Actually, both of my rules are impeccable. =d  Please refer to the University of Wisconsin's website! https://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/SubjectVerb.html (Giggle! Links are fun!) As to why your example is singular, it is singular because "drinking and driving" are little things called "gerunds" which are being joined to form a single gerund phrase for meaning--"drinking and driving" (and a gerund phrase is ALWAYS singular).  To apply the rule, actually use a compound subject as I stated:  "Drinking too much and driving too fast ARE serious problems."  I SAY, "GOOD DAY, SIR!"

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is specifically about what number to choose when the subjects are coordinated with “and/or”, rather than “and” or “or” on their own.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I would say you misinterpreted the question since the author of this post accepted my answer as satisfying his question.  Further, I contradicted snailboat in his reference to my answer, not a misinterpretation of my answer.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet By the way, in answer to your interpretation of his question, you would use the latest in time--"or".  Since we would define it using "or", we would follow the "or" rule.  "Annie and/or Tom is going to pay." (not are)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I have incorporated your interpretation of his question into my response.

Comment: Thank you—I've retracted my downvote. If you include inversion and especially contradicting subject numbers, though, things are less clear-cut. “Is your sister and/or brothers coming?” actually sounds _less_ natural to me than “Are your sister and/or brothers coming?”, even if “My sister and/or brothers are coming” is undoubtedly more natural than “My sister and/or brothers is coming” (which would be quite ungrammatical to me). But whereas there is a clear difference in acceptability between the latter two, neither of the former two sounds significantly more correct than the other to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You know that my rule still applies in the way you want to hear it, right?  "Are you sister and/or brothers coming?" "or" is the second in time which means we are looking at "brothers".  "Brothers" is plural, so we use "are". Edit: Oh I see what you are trying to do, you are placing the verb in front of the subject to change which subject is closest to the verb.  Interrogative sentences follow the same structure as they would if they were affirmative sentences.  I took it for granted that that was a given.  My apologies.  "My sister and/or brothers are" is the determiner.

Comment: For future reference, I'm neither a *his* nor a *sir*.  (I'm also frankly baffled that someone upvoted your comment.)

Comment: /sighs in sympathetic agreement.  I know! These rules that make up our language are tough.  /sighs again.  I guess we should just go by what "sounds good" to us. Hmmm... No.  I will continue with the foundational rules that make grammar a simple practice of memorization.